# Lattice Path Combinatorics: Given point find paths that pass through and avoid

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> I am given a lattice where one must start at (4, 4) and end at (15, 15). I have tried various measures to try solving this for the number of shortest paths where
>
> a) you must avoid the point (10,8) and
>
> b) pass through the point (10,8).

I'm aware that there is 1365 paths from (4, 4) to (15, 15). I have tried the approach where I try to generate all the paths that go through (10,8) from (4, 4) and then go from (10,8) to (15, 15) but I can't seem to find the answer or perhaps my approach in understanding the given point $(A, B)$ the number of shortest lattice paths to $(X,Y)$ is
$$\frac{(A-X)!\cdot (B-Y)!}{(A-X)! + (B-Y)!}$$

Comment: If I had written the problem, I would have reversed the order of parts (a) and (b) for reasons Robert Z's answer makes clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the number of [(North-East) lattice paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_path#North-East_lattice_paths) from  $(c,d)$  to  $(a,b)$ with $0\leq c\leq a$ and $0\leq d\leq b$ is equal to 
$$\binom{a-c+b-d}{a-c}=\binom{a-c+b-d}{b-d}=\frac{(a-c+b-d)!}{(a-c)!\cdot(b-d)!}.$$

Therefore we have that:

- from $(4,4)$ to $(15,15)$ there are $\binom{11+11}{11}=705432$ paths,
- from $(4,4)$ to $(10,8)$  there are $\binom{6+4}{4}=210$ paths,
- from $(10,8)$ to $(15,15)$ there are $\binom{5+7}{5}=792$ paths.

Hence, the answer for b) is $210\cdot 792=166320$ whereas the answer for a) is the complement $705432-166320=539112$.